# Preventing editor from changing meaning of the question

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question

I'm currently dealing with a high reputation editor that completely changes the meaning of the question with the editing of the title (and body), so that only his answer is correct, and all the other answers (including the most upvoted and accepted one), does not make any sense or are incorrect (they cannot be correct, because editor completely changed the meaning of the question).

I've reverted the change to the title, it went through the moderation process and was approved by several other reviewers. Only for the editor in question instantly reverting it back to his edit with one click.

Now he's also threatening to close the question because he claims the question does not make sense (keep in mind he claims that it doesn't make sense after his edits).

I'm completely lost how to proceed here. I don't want to be rude, but this person acts like he's a mind reader who knows better what was the intent of the original question better than the person asking *and* the person (not me) who provided the accepted answer.

This is the question in question ;) [How do you create a random string that's suitable for a session ID in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970795/how-do-you-create-a-suitable-session-id-in-postgresql)

The change is from:

- `How do you create a random string in PostgreSQL?`

to

- `How do you create a suitable session id in PostgreSQL?`

That, for me, completely changes the meaning of the question and invalidates most of the answers (including accepted and most-upvoted one).

Comment: hmmmmmm..... without seeing the question it's hard to say if the edit is warranted or not, but the 'I will close this' threat sounds super weird here...

Comment: Too many hypotheticals here. "Completely changing the meaning of the question" might be your interpretation, but it might also be that the user has more experience with whatever technology the question is about and tries to get to the crux of the problem. And "threating to close the question" might also be your interpretation...

Comment: I've edited the question with the link to the question and the edit.

Comment: Hmmmm... I see WHERE he's coming from, honestly..... but also, considering what happened on the question (accepting the answer that didn't touch session...), I am tempted to leave as is. Definitely an edge case... that I would leave as is to not invalidate anything.

Comment: Well that changes things. From such an old answer with many views and many answers... I agree with you here, the edit is not appropiate.

Comment: I see a user who answered a six-year-old question, edited the question to invalidate all the other answers, and left a comment on every existing answer promoting his own answer. That's pretty poor behavior.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've made an edit that I think fits well both for the new (and more modern) answer, which is great, as well as the existing answers in the context that they were given.

As far as edit disagreements go, this one stayed pretty tame - so I don't think there's further action to take, but I'd urge folks to ensure that subsequent edits leave room for all answers. As old questions get older, it's a *good* thing to see folks revisit them and provide new information - but at the same time once something gets rolled back more than a few times it's generally time to go hands off and just involve a mod.

I'm not locking the question at this point, but I will if it seems like things aren't finding their way to settling down.

Answer (score 5):

If you feel that this person is repeatedly defacing your question, just flag it explaining the problem (you can link to this question BTW) so a moderator can look at the edit history for the question and, high rep or not, he/she will take appropriate action amongst:

- warning the person
- temporary suspension
- account closure

Do NOT engage in serial downvoting / revenge downvoting or you'll be the bad guy (but you don't have to upvote his/her answers either :))

Comment: rep fine? first time I hear of that. You SURE of what you say? the three others, sure. But rep fine is an entirely new concept on Stack to me.

Comment: There's a 100 rep fine for 6 rude/abusive flags. Maybe not in this context. found it: "one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100". So doesn't apply to abusive edits but there's a rep fine: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation.

Comment: It's not his question.  The two simply disagree over the interpretation of the question.

Comment: Well I've actually upvoted  his answer as I think at this time (after 6 years) it's possibly the best answer to the (original) question. However I don't agree with changing the meaning of the question to fit the answer

Comment: but the editor obviously changes the question so his answer looks good and the others look bad. That's bad practice.

Comment: Note that I've edited my answer to remove the rep fine bit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The editor is improving the clarity of the question to make it clear that another, low quality, answer, is in fact a low quality answer.  That's not a bad practice.  Reverting the edit to make the question less clear, and as a result, give the false impression that a low quality answer is in fact a quality answer, is a bad practice.

Comment: @Servy The editor is defacing a question to make it mean what *they* think op meant. Sure, session identification and session *are* close, but if OP asks for how to create a random string, changing that to how to create a session Id is not ok. If they really felt so hard about it, they should have asked a new question, that said exactly what they meant, and answered it as well, not hijack an existing settled down question. I think..

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier They edited the title of the question to reflect the body of the question, because the title the OP gave was oversimplified to the point that it resulted in people misunderstanding it.  The body of the question made it clear that the random string was to be used for a session key, and so any random string wouldn't do.  Some people read the title, didn't look at the body of the question at all, and as a result, posted incorrect answers.  To avoid this, the editor made the title more accurately reflect **the OP's stated question**.